# how to make a clickable phone numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I want to archive, is the possibility for the user to have clickable phone numbers on my android (webview) phone numbers search app.

My question is, how do I attach `<a href="tel:?xxx">` for entry.mobile ?

my controller

```
    @a = Hash.new
  ldap.search(:base => treebase1, :filter => filter1) do |entry|
      mobile = ""
      if entry.respond_to?("mobile")
        mobile = entry.mobile
      end
   telephonenumber = ""
      if entry.respond_to?("telephonenumber")
        telephonenumber = entry.telephonenumber
      end

      name = ""
      if entry.respond_to?("cn")
        name = entry.cn
      end

      mail = ""
      if entry.respond_to?("mail")
        mail = entry.mail
      end

      title = ""
      if entry.respond_to?("title")
        title = entry.title
      end

      @a[name] = {:pareigos => title, :tel => telephonenumber, :mobilus => mobile, :ep => mail }
  end
```

my view

```
    <% @a.each do |attribute, values| %>
          <%= attribute.first.to_s.force_encoding("UTF-8") %>
              <ul>
               <h2><% values.each do |name, value|%></h2>
                 <% if !value[0].nil? %>
                  <li><%= name.capitalize %>:
                     <%= value[0].to_s.force_encoding("UTF-8") %></li>
                      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This will cause invalid HTML `<h2><% values.each do |name, value|%></h2>` as the opening `h2` tag is outside the `each` loop, and the closing `h2` tag is inside the loop. So there will be one opening tag and many closing tags. I expect the `h2` tags need removing.

Comment: Thanks for spoting the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if I understand your question correctly. I'll give it a try.

I kept the example simple (without building a hash), since you asked how to render a `<a href=""></a>` element with clickable phone number.

In your controller you can just set your view variable:

```
@mobile = "12345678"
```

Then in your view:

```
<a href="tel:?<%= @mobile %>"><%= @mobile </a>
```

*If these values are optional, obviously you should implement some checking whether to render these fields.*

// Off topic.
Have a look at [HAML](http://haml.info), this type of code (via ERB) gets very quickly unreadable

Comment: Haml is soo old. One should use Slim :) (or is there a newer tool)?

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it ! ;)

Comment: I solved this like that <a href="tel:<%= values[:mobilus][0] %>"><a>. Thanks.

Comment: @Geeedas  great! you can also use: values[:mobilus].first